# Mockito Java 8 argument matcher any(Class <T>)

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I need to pass Class  to argument matcher. Here is what I am doing and my match should return object apiResponse which is not null since I am creating it and passing it along. But, it does not seem to be injecting it; I receive it as null.

I have tried it also with ArgumentMatchers.eq(ApiResponse.class),Mockito.eq(ApiResponse.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(ApiResponse.class) and Mockito.any(ApiResponse.class).

With ArgumentMatchers.any(ApiResponse.class) and Mockito.any(ApiResponse.class), the code won't even compile, and with ArgumentMatchers.eq(ApiResponse.class),Mockito.eq(ApiResponse.class), I receive null on the other side. Please suggest!

```
      ApiResponse apiResponse = new ApiResponse();
      apiResponse.setErrcode("0");
      apiResponse.setNum_fields_changed("1");
      Mockito.when(xmlResponseMapper.parseXMLToObject(any(String.class),ArgumentMatchers.eq(ApiResponse.class))).thenReturn((apiResponse));
```

Here is where I use this matcher in my class

```
  apiResponse = xmlResponseMapper.parseXMLToObject(response.getBody(), ApiResponse.class);
```

Did I do something wrong? I am using Java 8.

Comment: what is the signature of parseXMLToObject method?

Comment: public <T> T parseXMLToObject(String xmlResponse, Class<T> x) throws JAXBException,XMLStreamException{

Comment: how do you mock xmlResponseMapper?

Comment: @Mock
  private XmlResponseMapper xmlResponseMapper;

Comment: Class<T> doesn't implement .equals(). Can you run this in the debugger and confirm that the ApiResponse.class in your matcher and the ApiResponse.class in your code under test are both references to the same object in memory?

Comment: How can I find out if they map to same object in the memory?

Answer (score 1):

It is solved. The issue was actually not with ArgumentMatchers.eq(ApiResponse.class) but with the String, the first parameter being passed in the matcher

```
  Mockito.when(xmlResponseMapper.parseXMLToObject(any(String.class),ArgumentMatchers.eq(ApiResponse.class))).thenReturn((apiResponse));
```

I was passing null as the first parameter. Once I passed a dummy string, it all went fine and I received apiResponse on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

> With ArgumentMatchers.any(ApiResponse.class) and
>   Mockito.any(ApiResponse.class), the code won't even compile

As your method expects a class type, those matchers return an object of specified type.

You need to specify the matcher with the exact class that that you intend to pass:

```
Mockito.when(xmlResponseMapper.parseXMLToObject(any(String.class),
 ArgumentMatchers.eq(QuickBaseApiResponse.class))).thenReturn((apiResponse));
```

If you pass the `ApiResponse` to `eq()`, then there wont be a match as `ApiResponse.class` and `QuickBaseApiResponse.class` are different instances and the method will always resolve to false.

Also the `apiResponse` needs to be of type `QuickBaseApiResponse`.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the confusion. But, I am passing       Mockito.when(xmlResponseMapper.parseXMLToObject(any(String.class),ArgumentMatchers.eq(QuickBaseApiResponse.class))).thenReturn((quickBaseApiResponse));
I just edited the QuickBaseApiResponse toApiResponse in the question to keep it small.

Comment: ok so, the bottom line is that you pass the exact same class in the implementation as in the Mockito.eq() right?

Comment: which version of Mockito?

Comment: <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.5</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>